# Obtaining location of qr code using Pyzbar

Tags: zbar

I've been using pyzbar recently as zbar is not supported in python 3. Is there a way to detect the location (4 corners) of a qr code? It was easy in zbar wherein symbol.location() would display the coordinates of the four corners of the qr code.

Comment: Share some code so that people can help you.

Answer (score 1):

### Description

The following code computes the corner coordinates of a rectangular qr code if it is detected by `pyzbar`.

### Verification

The code is verified in a python 3.6 environment in Anaconda Prompt 4.8.3 on Windows 10 Pro N X64. In that operating system it requires Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 to be installed. Instructions to realize this setup can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63296571/decode-a-qr-code-in-python-3-6-in-anaconda-4-8-3-on-64-bit-windows/63299174?noredirect=1#comment111932254_63299174).

## Code

```
# import libraries
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image

# read the qr code from an image
qrcode = decode(Image.open('test6.png'))


# Get the rect/contour coordinates:
left = qrcode[0].rect[0]
top = qrcode[0].rect[1]
width = qrcode[0].rect[2]
height = qrcode[0].rect[3]
print(f'left={left},top={top},width={width},height={height}')

# get the rectangular contour corner coordinates
top_left = [top,left]
print(f'top_left={top_left}')
top_right = [top,left+width]
print(f'top_right={top_right}')
bottom_left = [top-height,left]
print(f'bottom_left={bottom_left}')
bottom_right = [top-height,left+width]
print(f'bottom_right={bottom_right}')
```

## Code Explanation

Note the `decode(Image.open('test6.png'))` returns a list with in its first element: `Decoded(data=b'9', type='QRCODE', rect=Rect(left=11, top=179, width=90, height=89), polygon=[Point(x=11, y=179), Point(x=11, y=268), Point(x=101, y=268), Point(x=101, y=179)])` (but with data/properties of the qr code that you test it on). Therefore, the `qrcode[0].rect` object returns the 4 rectangular properties `left`,`top`,`width` and `height` of the qr code. The second index in for example `qrcode[0].rect[3]` is used to select specific rectangular properties of the qr code. These specific rectangular properties of the qr code are then used to compute the corner coordinates of the qr code.

Comment: addition, if pyzbar detects "n" qrcode/barcodes, the list mentioned above will have each object in one of the indices (i.e. the first object in index 0, the n-th  in index n-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the bounding box location of the barcode as below.

```
barcodes = pyzbar.decode(image)
(x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
```

Where x and y are the starting coordinate, and w and h are the width and height of the bounding box.