# Decode a qr-code in Python 3.6 in Anaconda 4.8.3 on 64 bit Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, decode, qr-code

*How can I decode a qr code in python 3.6 in Anaconda 4.8.3 a Windows 10 Pro N 64 bit installation?*

Most solutions require Pillow with `zbar`. However, [it appears](https://anaconda.org/sci-bots/pyzbar) `zbar` is only available on 32bit
windows installations. Furthermore, `pip install zbarlight` yields:

> `ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyzbarlight`

To try and decode a qr code in python 3.6 in Anaconda 4.8.3 on a Windows 10 Pro N 64 bit device, I tried the following code:

```
# Set up virtual environment in Anaconda
# conda create --name test36 python=3.6
# conda activate test36

# Install pip in the `test36` environment:
# E:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/test36/Scripts/pip install pyzbar

# Source: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pillow
# conda install -c anaconda pillow

from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image
decode(Image.open('elbow.png'))
```

Which yields error:

> `OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows error message**

If you see an ugly ImportError when importing pyzbar on Windows you will most likely need the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013. Install vcredist_x64.exe if using 64-bit Python, vcredist_x86.exe if using 32-bit Python.

visit and read please here https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/ or github homepage https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar

I use Ubuntu for my purposes, so I cannot check this out, but in home project README they give information about ugly  ImportError. **If they talk about 64 bit installation, then pyazbar works on 64-bit Windows, please doublecheck that Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 is properly installed and other requirements are satisfied also.**

Comment: Thank you, I had the incorrect link or conflicting Visual C++ Redistributable Packages. First I removed all existing Visual C++ Redistributable Packages. Next I downloaded and installed the `vcredist_x64.exe` from https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784 as shown on the git of pyzbar. I closed and re-opened Anaconda Prompt and verified your answer/the code works with the correct Visual C++ Package in a python 3.6 environment on Anaconda 4.8.3 on x64 Windows 10.

Comment: @a.t. You're welcome. By the way, if no pyzbar in Anaconda for x64 Windows(I have checked your conda package link with only x32 available). Install it just via pip. Firstly packages go to pypi and then conda copies them to conda repository (Not sure, but I think it works this way)

Answer (score 0):

To recap the following steps enabled decoding a qr code in a python 3.6 environment in Anaconda prompt 4.8.3 on a 64 Windows 10 Pro N device:

The steps assume python 3.6 environment is installed and activated, which can be done with.

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda
conda activate py36
```

#### Pillow installation

Source:https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pillow

Command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pillow
```

#### Pyzbar installation

Source: [Decode a qr-code in Python 3.6 in Anaconda 4.8.3 on 64 bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63296571/decode-a-qr-code-in-python-3-6-in-anaconda-4-8-3-on-64-bit-windows)

Command:

```
pip install pyzbar
```

Then from source: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784
download `vcredist_x64.exe` (if you have an 64 bit pc, for x86 pick the 32 bit version).
You don't even have to restart anaconda prompt and you can verify pyzbar with a python file named `test.py` with content:

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
decode(Image.open('test.png'))
```

Next include an image named `test.png` in the same folder as `test.py`.
You can execute  `test.py` in Anaconda prompt in a python 3.6 environment with command:

```
python test.py
```

It shouldn't output anything.